Apache with prefork MPM acting as reverse proxy for WebSockets service - bad idea?
I'm trying to implement a WebSockets service. But my infrastructure is limited to Apache with PHP and Apache must use the prefork MPM :(
I'm planning to implement the service with something like Laravel, but I'm mainly worried about the Apache config.
If I configure Apache to do the reverse proxy work, would then be one full Apache process kept for each alive WebSockets connection? Or can one Apache process handle multiple WebSockets connections?
Any info would be greatly appreciated!
J.

After some research, I came to this conclusion:
It depends in the MPM (Multi Processing Module) used. In Apache, the default MPM is "prefork" which uses one full process for each connection - also for WebSocket connections in Reverse Proxy mode.
So if you want to avoid that (to save server resources), then you need to switch to a different MPM - like "event". In that model Apache uses threads to serve multiple connections per process.
Note: As PHP (normally) is not thread-safe, this also means that you need to switch from mod_php to PHP-FPM.
